# send data from notification to activity and make activity behave accordingly

Tags: android, notifications

I have two types of notifications, downloading and uploading notifications.
It will open a Activity by clicking the notification, and the Activity has two fragment tabs, one used for downloading and one used for uploading.
What I want is, when click the uploading notification, it not only start the Activity but open the specific tab, same thing with the download part.

Below is what I have done.

```
 // configure the intent
    Intent dIntent = new Intent(this, TransferActivity.class);
    dIntent.putExtra(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_KEY, WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_OPEN_DOWNLOAD_TAB); // open download task tab
    dIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent dPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, dIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    downloadNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_bar_downloading, getString(R.string.notification_bar_title_download_started), System.currentTimeMillis());
    downloadNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    downloadNotification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_bar_progress_layout);
    downloadNotification.contentIntent = dPendingIntent;

    Intent uIntent = new Intent(this, TransferActivity.class);
    uIntent.putExtra(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_KEY, WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_OPEN_UPLOAD_TAB); // open upload task tab
    uIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent uPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, uIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    uploadNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_bar_uploading, getString(R.string.notification_bar_title_upload_started), System.currentTimeMillis());
    uploadNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    uploadNotification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_bar_progress_layout);
    uploadNotification.contentIntent = uPendingIntent;

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I process the passed data in Activity like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        onNewIntent(getIntent());
    }

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_KEY)) {
                // extract the extra-data in the Notification
                String msg = extras.getString(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_KEY);
                if (msg.equals(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_OPEN_DOWNLOAD_TAB)) {
                    currentPosition = 0;
                    indicator.setCurrentItem(0);
                } else if (msg.equals(WidgetUtils.NOTIFICATION_OPEN_UPLOAD_TAB)) {
                    currentPosition = 1;
                    indicator.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem is it always start the Upload tab no matter which type of notification I clicked. Which is really confusing.
Anyone can help?
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please check if `onNewIntent` is getting called?

Comment: it always get called, but the result is always open the upload tab even I click the downloading notification

Comment: Theer is some problem with the `Intent` which is received. Can you check my answer and let me know if that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar problem in the recent past. After few investigation, I found that `onNewIntent` was being called on same `Intent`. I ended up using a workaround which worked perfectly fine for me. I will share that with you.

1. Instead of calling `TransferActivity` through `Intent`, introduce a middle man `NotificationChannelActivity`. All clicks on notification will then be channelized to this middle man.
2. Extract the data passed through `Intent` in middle man and pass them to `TransferActivity`. You can extract data using `getIntent` API and then repack it in a new `Intent` and kick off `TransferActivity` where the actual handling of data will be done.
3. Use unique identitier in the `PendingIntent:

   int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
   PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), iUniqueId, uIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: What is current state? Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: yes, I have fixed it, see the code [here](https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/blob/notifications/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/ui/NotificationUtils.java)

Comment: Cool :) Seems like Step #3 worked for you. You can accept the answer. It would help future readers.

Comment: This helped me +1 for that .

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent) your onNewIntent might not get called.

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.
> So, if your activity is a normal one, you should use the intent from getIntent(), in onCreate() or onResume().

Also, to treat both cases, you can consider calling setIntent() in onNewIntent() and just using getIntent in onResume() as it suggests in the documentation.